# Jekyll - Change frontmatter variables for each environment variable

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Im trying to output front matter variables depending on the current Jekyll environment.

For example, if the current environment is `dev` I would like the variable `dev` to be displayed:

```
---
something:
  dev: "Some text"
  production: "Other text
---
```

I'm trying to access the variable dev with the following method and I get no result:

`{{ page.something.jekyll.environment }}`

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can access front matter in this way.

Instead, you coud assign the `dev` variable in your html template, with the environment as a conditional:

```
---
layout: default
---
{% if jekyll.environment == "dev" %}
{% assign dev = "this is dev" %}
{% endif %}

<div id="page-content">
{{dev}}
...
</div>
```

You could also directly wrap the relevant element in an if statement in the template.

Comment: This worked out to be the best solution for what I'm doing. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The right syntax is : `{{ page.something[jekyll.environment] }}`.

Note that locally `jekyll.environment` is "**development**" and not "dev".